# Bash HTTPie works when calling STRAVA script through command line but not through crontab

Tags: bash, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux, strava

I'm new to shell scripting and I have a Bash script pulling in data from the Strava API and manipulating/reading it using jq.

When I copy and paste in the first line of code (the one calling in data) into the command line, it works. When I run `bash strava.sh` the entire program works. But when I execute the program through crontab, I'm getting the following error:

```
usage: http [--json] [--form] [--pretty {all,colors,format,none}]
            [--style STYLE] [--print WHAT] [--headers] [--body] [--verbose]
            [--all] [--history-print WHAT] [--stream] [--output FILE]
            [--download] [--continue]
            [--session SESSION_NAME_OR_PATH | --session-read-only SESSION_NAME_OR_PATH]
            [--auth USER[:PASS]] [--auth-type {basic,digest}]
            [--proxy PROTOCOL:PROXY_URL] [--follow]
            [--max-redirects MAX_REDIRECTS] [--timeout SECONDS]
            [--check-status] [--verify VERIFY]
            [--ssl {ssl2.3,tls1,tls1.1,tls1.2}] [--cert CERT]
            [--cert-key CERT_KEY] [--ignore-stdin] [--help] [--version]
            [--traceback] [--default-scheme DEFAULT_SCHEME] [--debug]
            [METHOD] URL [REQUEST_ITEM [REQUEST_ITEM ...]]
http: error: unrecognized arguments: https://www.strava.com/oauth/token client_id=xxx client_secret=xxx refresh_token=xxx grant_type=refresh_token
```

Here's what the line looks like in my script:

```
access_token=$(http POST "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token" client_id="xxx" client_secret="xxx" refresh_token="xxx" grant_type="refresh_token" | jq -r '.access_token')
```

When running through crontab, the above error is printed on the first line (i.e. line given above), so I'm fairly certain the problem lies in that line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The httpie manual (https://httpie.io/docs/cli/best-practices) advises to use of:

```
--ignore-stdin
```

For "non-interactive invocations".

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a path issue - are there multiple copies of http installed?

Is there a "`%`" anywhere in your parameters?  Crontab interprets % as a newline, so if you'll have to escape it - "`%%`".

As an aside - please put your subshell inside "s, lest one day strava returns something like "`AC0f4;rm * 0cd-4b203`"

```
access_token="$( http POST ...
```